# Not able to reach container running in a localhost docker swarm cluster

Tags: windows, docker, java, docker-compose, docker-swarm

If that's interesting: OS: WIN10 (cygwin), code written in `Java`. I am using hyperv VMs as stated in this guide: [this](https://forums.docker.com/t/get-started-part-4-swarms-connection-refused/63317)

> I'd expect to reach the `service` in front of the `container`, which is running on port 80, using `myvm1IP:80` (browser ir curl). Somehow this does not work. Or am I missunderstanding the service port forwarding?
>
> ***:8080->80/tcp**

---

I got a running docker swarm cluster consisting of 2 nodes. 
**I am able to ping both of the running VMs**

I already downgraded the version as there were [issues with more recent version numbers](https://forums.docker.com/t/get-started-part-4-swarms-connection-refused/63317). Information about the engine using `docker inspect vmName`:

```
    "Engine": {
        "EngineVersion": "18.06.1-ce",
        "Labels": {
            "provider": "hyperv"
        },
```

I executed the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: elps/articleservice:1.1.0.4
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=192.168.178.82
      - MYSQL_DB=article
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=abcdefg
    networks:
      - webnet    

networks:
  webnet:
```

Both replicas started successfully and are able to connect to the local running database (assuming that, as I had a look at the logs and everything was looking fine). The container are up and running.

> **Output of docker ps -a**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
979ed7ea88b7        elps/articleservice:1.1.0.4   "java -jar articlese…"   27 minutes ago      Up 27 minutes               8080/tcp            getstartedlab_web.1.j1j41so8pz6atxqnq9fqqquk7
7684c3667025        elps/articleservice:1.1.0.4   "java -jar articlese…"   27 minutes ago      Up 27 minutes               8080/tcp            getstartedlab_web.2.r4kadvztiwgpckkuannnhcsea
```

> **Output of docker service ls**

```
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                         PORTS
gvyi9moxtpvq        getstartedlab_web   replicated          2/2                 elps/articleservice:1.1.0.4   *:8080->80/tcp
```

> **Output of docker-machine ls**

```
NAME    ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER        ERRORS
myvm1   *        hyperv   Running   tcp://192.168.178.88:2376           v18.06.1-ce
myvm2   -        hyperv   Running   tcp://192.168.178.89:2376           v18.06.1-ce
```

When I try to execute `curl myvmIP:80` I recieve

> Failed to connect to 192.168.178.88 port 80: Connection refused

as response. I'd expect recieving a `404` error code as there is no mapping for `/`. Am I wrong with this?

Comment: You exposed port 8080, not port 80.

Comment: Sorry, the service (which is some kind of proxy in front of the container) runs on port 80. Attached that information above.

Comment: Jesus christ, I totally missunderstood your answer I think... If you'd like to you can provide this as answer and get the bounty.